# From which episode of Star Trek TNG is the lower part of the picture?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification, riker

I mean the one with Riker on the screen.

[image: Fire At Will]

Comment: Hah! It's funny because that Riker would literally rather have Picard kill him than go back to his horrific, nightmare reality! :)

Comment: @DavidS Alternatively because that Will actually did get fired on and blown up. ...Or maybe that's not so funny.

Comment: Ohhhh, so that's why the weapon's officers always wait for an order to fire, even in most obvious situations. It's because their XO hates firing at Will :) ("They cannot fire at Will/will") :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Season 7, Episode 11 (Parallels)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallels_%28episode%29)

[image]

Comment: gave it a little help - Paulj can add any sizzle text to the answer as needed (I would if it were me)

Comment: The first thing that appears in a google image search for "Season 7, Episode 11 (Parallels)" is the requested image. The question wasn't "prove what episode" or "what time index was..." or "where in the script...". Thank you for adding the clips, but I answered precisely, without assuming what the originator of the question may or may not require.

Comment: @Paulj It is often appreciated to go the extra mile though.

Comment: @Paulj the thing with your initial answer is that no one could know you had answered correctly without doing extra research themselves. Answers should really be self contained with the evidence in them to come to the same conclusion.

Comment: It was also a community kindness that folks with higher rep that know how to craft well-received and up-voted answers didn't just make their own answer that, though later, would likely receive more up-votes, but rather edited and offered suggestions for your admittedly correct and first answer :)

Comment: "but I answered precisely, without assuming what the originator of the question may or may not require" - one thing to consider is that in this community, and SE overall, you aren't just answering for the OP, but for posterity and Google to be a bit more crude. The more information you can add helps future searches looking for information about the topic in question. (This isn't to say you should duplicate the entire memory-alpha article, but more detail and text rather than links that may indeed go dead are helpful and appreciated)

Comment: I don't disagree with the efforts made to improve my answer, I understand the reasoning. However, conceptually, why bother voting answers up or down, if there's just one community edited answer? Shouldn't my answer have been downvoted as 'low quality' after another user posted an improved answer? I feel all we've done is remove a chance for another user to shine.

Comment: @Paulj Your answer is yours, and you can feel free to roll back any edits made by other users if you disagree with them.  We'd like you to join our community and feel welcome here, though, and downvoting a new(ish) user into obscurity only to have someone else post the same answer with more citations isn't the best way to encourage that.  *This particular question* is fairly specific, so there's no need for 5 answers that all say basically the same thing (hence editing yours), but other questions on the site do have, and indeed benefit from, multiple answers with different perspectives.

Comment: You might find this page from the [FAQ] to be useful; [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/editing). *"Common reasons for edits include... *To add related resources or hyperlinks*"

Comment: @Paulj That's kind of a weakness of easy "episode identification" questions: although there's nothing stopping somebody from posting a competing answer with a different conclusion, the odds of anyone getting this question "wrong" are so small that there is likely to only ever be one answer posted here. Any other answers posted would have the same content, just in a different form or with more citations. As such, it's cleaner to just polish the one that exists already. It's often a fuzzy line between adding new answers and improving existing ones, but in this instance it seems pretty clear cut.

Comment: @Paulj As a fairly frequent poster on the more technical exchange sites (Unix&Linux, Webmasters, AskUbuntu etc), please don't let the fact that you lose reputation, or are judged more harshly on some questions prevent you from answering them.  I have found that users on exchange sites tend to be a bit more critical as our answers are Googled by a plethora of visitors.  The more your answers are seen and validated as correct(which this one was), the easier the reputation will come.  Hang in there and thanks for contributing.

Comment: Many thanks. Yeah - the episode identification was enough but I appreciate all the other details.